# Left adjoint to pullback functor ($\Sigma$) vs coproduct in cartesian categories

Tags: category-theory

Let A be an object in a cartesian category $\mathscr C$.
Let $I$ denote the terminal object of $\mathscr C$.
Consider the forgetful functor $\Sigma_A:\mathscr C/A\to\mathscr C$, which is 
left adjont to the pullback functor along $A\to I$.
For $B:Y\to A$, we clearly have $\Sigma_A(B)=Y$.

For each $a:I\to A$ let $B(a)$ defined by the following pullback square:

$\matrix{
B(a)&\to&I\\
\downarrow&&\downarrow a\\
\Sigma_A(B)&\xrightarrow[B]{}&A
}$

Question: The following isomorphism holds $$\Sigma_A(B)\cong\coprod_{a:I\to A}B(a)?$$

The morphisms $B(a)\to\Sigma_A(B)$ in the pullback square serves as inclusion morphisms.
However, given a co-cone $y_a:B(a)\to Y'$, for $a:I\to A$, I can't find a way to get a morphism $\Sigma_A(B)\to Y'$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The isomorphism doesn't hold if you mean the coproduct indexed by elements of the *set* $\text{Hom}(1, A)$, i.e. a colimit indexed by a discrete category as opposed to a colimit indexed by the comma category.  Basically, $Y$ may be connected in a way that is lost by the coproduct.  Here's an explicit counter-example in $\mathbf{Top}$, which is complete and cocomplete.

Let $\Omega$ be the Sierpiński space $(\{\bot,\top\},\{\emptyset,\{\top\},\Omega\})$.  Then the pullback of $\top : 1 \to \Omega$ along any continuous function $f : X \to \Omega$ is an open subset of $X$.  In particular, for $X = \Omega$ we have $0$, $1 \cong \{\top\}$, and $\Omega$ as the open subsets of $\Omega$ up to isomorphism. $0 + 1 + \Omega \cong 1 + \Omega \ncong \Omega$.